# remove type from function with template return value

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following classes:

```
class A {
public:
  virtual std::string Serialize();
  virtual void Deserialize(std::string);

  template <typename T>
  T* Clone()
  {
    std::string s = Serialize();
    T* t = new T();
    t->Deserialize(s);
    return t;
  }
};

class B : public A {
public:
  std::string Serialize() { ... }
  void Deserialize(std::string) { ... }
};
```

Now, if I want to clone B, I do the following:

```
B b1;
B* b2 = b1.Clone<B>();
```

Is there any way to remove the template type without re-implementing `Clone` in each and every derived classes?

I want something like this:

```
B b1;
B* b2 = b1.Clone();
```

Comment: Did you mean `b1.Clone<B>()` ?

Comment: @NirFriedman thanks, corrected.

Comment: not sure, but maybe this can help: [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)

Comment: `B.Clone<B>()` would not compile.   If you mean `b1.Clone<B>()` then a solution would be for the function to accept an argument of type `T`.   For example, `T *Clone(T *) { ...}` which would be called as `B *b2 = b1.Clone(b2)`.         With a template function, it is necessary to provide some means at the call site that the compiler can unambiguously deduce the required type.  `b1.Clone()` does not do that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The way to do this is with CRTP:

```
class A {
public:
    virtual std::string Serialize();
    virtual void Deserialize(std::string);
    virtual A* Clone() = 0;  
};

template <class T>
class HelperA : public A {

    T* Clone() override
        {
            std::string s = Serialize();
            T* t = new T();
            t->Deserialize(s);
            return t;
        }
};

class B : public HelperA<B> {
public:
    std::string Serialize() { ... }
    void Deserialize(std::string) { ... }
};
```

These 3 level hierarchies are quite common. Basically, the top class is pure interface, as before (note: you should = 0 the other functions too). The middle class uses the CRTP pattern: it is templated on the derived typed. the idea is that by having static access to the derived type, it can automatically implement things like `Clone`. Then the derived type implements any implementation that cannot be done generically.

Notice that the derived-most type inherits from the CRTP class templated on itself. That's where the name comes from (Curiously Recurring Template Pattern). Of course, since inheritance is transitive B also inherits from A still, as originally, enabling the same sort of things.

Here is a full working example that you can execute: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8f2b201a06b5abcc. I kept the code in the answer as similar to the question as possible, but in the coliru example there are a few small but important differences:

- usage of owning pointers instead of raw pointers considered good practice in C++, and because smart pointers are not covariant this affects the signatures
- correct use of = 0 and override, as well as const
- an example of the static downcast which is kind of a signature of CRTP that didn't come up with your example

Comment: May I ask, why implement clone as serialize/deserialize pair?

Comment: @PasserBy I have no idea, it was in OP's code, doesn't really seem to be germane to what he's asking though unless I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: `Clone` should probably be `const` :)

Comment: @Quentin I wanted to minimize change to the original code to draw attention to the heart of the matter, I didn't fix override or other things so why fix const correctness? That said, I did fix my coliru example and I noted it in the answer. Hope that addresses your concern :-). Thanks for pointing that out!